# Wrapping Applications with a .bat Script

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I recently decided to start using Google's command-line JavaScript compiler (Closure Compiler) to minify JavaScript in my web application. Unfortunately, the compiler is written in Java so the command I have to type to use the compiler is somewhat cumbersome:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js hello.js --js_output_file hello-compiled.js
```

What would be the simplest way for me to wrap this in .bat file that would allow me to simply type `closure hello.js hello-compiled.js`, while still allowing me to use closure's other command line flags such as `--warning-level` and `--help`?

Comment: Suggest you consider using [tag:powershell], instead.

Comment: @David Why? What does powershell have that helps resolve this problem? Actually, what makes you think I'm not using powershell already?

Comment: Well, it's more akin to a command shell, like what you would find in Unix or Linux.  It has a rich interface, and also gives you access to .Net objects and methods.  In general, the Microsoft world had been moving away from cmd and batch files and toward powershell for several years now.  I find it much more powerful and much easier to use.  Out with the old and in with the new, so to speak.  In your case, you could create a simple powershell script to implement your command line, then add an alias to your powershell config that would enable you to call it from the powershell command line.

Comment: What makes you think that I think that you're not using powershell?  Regardless of whether you're using it already, or not, I merely suggested it as an alternative.

Comment: @David Right now I'm actually using git bash, but I'll definitely look into powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:Start
   @echo off
   if "%1"=="" Echo Error - input and output parameters were not specified.&goto End
   if "%2"=="" Echo Error - output parameter was not specified.&goto End
   if not exist %1 Echo Error - input file does not exist.&goto End
   set infile=%1
   set outfile=%2
   set "params="
:Loop
   if "%3"=="" goto Continue
   set params=%params% %3
   shift
   goto Loop
:Continue
   java -jar compiler.jar --js %infile% --js_output_file %outfile% %params%
   set "infile="
   set "outfile="
   set "params="
:End
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how automated you want this to be, but this will prompt you for your script, your compiled output file, and if you want any extra parameters.

Easily editable if you want more options.

```
@echo off
set /p script=Script file:
set /p compiled=Compiled script:
set /p params=Enter any extra params (leave blank if none):
if defined params (
java -jar compiler.jar --js %script% --js_output_file %compiled% %params%
) else (
java -jar compiler.jar --js %script% --js_output_file %compiled%
)
echo Done
pause >nul
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I'm looking for. I'd like to be able to run the command in one line though instead of having the script prompt me separately for each parameter.